# ¿A qué se debe el problema Android studio, "Waiting for target device to come online"?

Tags: android-studio

He estado programando en Android studio y utilizando enlaces a páginas web en la aplicación.

Al intentar recrear la aplicación en cualquiera de los emuladores, el programa se queda esperando, mostrando el mensaje:

> ```
> Waiting for target device to come online
> ```

La conexión a internet es buena y he instalado correctamente el APK de cada emulador.

Me gustaría saber a qué se puede estar debiendo este problema.

**Actualización:**
He añadido la siguiente línea que parece haber solucionado el problema, por si a alguien le resulta de ayuda:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: **Esto no tiene que ver con permisos de internet, tiene que ver con la conexión del ADB con el emulador o dispositivo.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He añadidola siguiente línea que parece haber solucionado el problema, por si a alguien le resulta de ayuda:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

> Waiting for target device to come online

Si se muestra este mensaje y no inicia la carga de tu aplicación es seguramente porque tienes alguna instancia activa que esta provocando problemas, generalmente ocurre por algún problema con el `ADB`.

Veo que comentas:

> La conexión a internet es buena y he instalado correctamente el APK de
>   cada emulador.

Este detalle no tiene que ver con la conexión a internet, cierra todos tus emuladores y reinicia el `ADB`, para esto abre el `Android Device Monitor` y ve a la opción indicada en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como otra opción, simplemente cierra todas las ventanas y reinicia `android studio`, para que reinicie el `ADB`.

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje se refiere a que Android Studio está esperando que el Emulador que seleccionaste para correr la app se termine de "prender" para así instalarle el apk de tu app.

Si efectivamente vos ves que el emulador arrancó y esta ejecutando sin problema puede tratarse de un problema con el programa *adb* con el que Android Studio se conecta los dispositivos y emuladores.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta cerrar android studio, luego dirigete a cmd y escribre adb kill-server. Para terminar con el servicio de adb, esto cerrara todas las conexiones que tiene adb. Si sigues teniendo problemas prueba a deshabilitar tu firewall, que en ocaciones puede que este bloqueando la conexión local de adb hacia el emulator. Si te funciona lo del firewall, agrega una regla manual para el adb.

Comment: Ignora lo del firewall, tienes varias conexiones a emuladores. Suficiente es con cerrar el adb desde cmd.

Answer (score 1):

He buscado por todos lados y encontré la solución y es bastante sencilla, hacer lo siguiente:

1. abrir el AVD y si ya tienes instalado un Emulador como el Nexus 5X, borralo.
2. instala un nuevo emulador en este caso yo puse nuevamente el Nexus 5X API 24, PERO, hay que hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

   - En Select a system image: yo usé el Nougat Android 7.0 (**GOOGLE PLAY**).
   - En x86 Images: también hay que marcar Nougat x86_64 y siempre el que dice Android 7.0 (**GOOGLE APIs**) esto último es muy importante.
   - ahora recién pones NEXT y luego que instale FINISH.

Listo!!! corre nuevamente tu app ;)

Answer (score 1):

Bueno comento la idea que me ha solucionado el problema.

- En el emulador desconectar el ADB en linea
- Seleccionar el archivo ADB.EXE desde Users.

Comment: ¿Al seleccionar el archivo ADB.exe que se realiza?

Answer (score 1):

Desactiva el firewall de windows o agrega adb en la lista de excepciones, en el caso de que tengas avast desactiva el cortafuegos de allí, y déjaselo en manos de windows a mi me funciono, tengo win 10

Answer (score -1):

En "Tools", en "AVD Manager", encima del dispositivo que estés usando, botón derecho y "Wipe Data".
Me funciono perfecto a mi.